# Why does django admin inline save fails when inline contains readonly primary key?

Tags: django, django-admin

Why isn't it possible to have a **readonly** inline related object in the django admin?

In the example below, as soon as I add `id` in the `readonly_fields`, it breaks when trying to save the `OtherFoo` model.

I found this [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26934) in the django project that was closed years ago and the alternate ticket does not help.

```
class FooInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Foo

    fields = (
        "id",
        "link",
        "content",
    )
    readonly_fields = (
        "id", # <===============
        "link",
        "content",
    )

class OtherFooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = [
        FooInline,
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm remembering correctly, readonly fields don't actually post their values when the form is posted. What I've done to fix this is to make a custom admin form that has a custom clean method that sorta injects that value back into the form.

This is ripped from my own code:

```py
class FooAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        exclude = ['name']

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.get('id') or 'id' in kwargs.get('initial'):
            self.fields['id'].widget.attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': 'true'}
        return self

    def clean_id(self):
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            return instance.id
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['id']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I could not make this work. There were several errors along the way that I tried to fix without success. There must be more to it. I don't understand why django does not even support this in the first place as it seems so basic. Weird.

Comment: Well it's not a Django problem, it's an HTML problem. HTML handles the `<form>` submit, Django just generates them. But sorry you had no luck with my solution :(

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar issue. I solved it using the following:

```
class FooAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['id'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True


class FooInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Foo
    extra = 0
    form = FooAdminForm

    fieldsets = ((None, {"fields": (
        "id",
        "field_a",
        "field_b",

     )}),)

@admin.register(FooBarModel)
class FooBarModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [FooInline]
```